# Missing Directory in Apache Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I have accidentally deleted my directory in Webapp folder of apache tomcat. Is there any way to retrieve that directory in tomcat. It is not present in recycle bin.

Answer (score 0):

if you have deleted webapps folder of tomcat there is no problem, just start again tomcat and it will appear. After that you can put you app in created webapps folder and everything have to be OK.

If you are deleted your web application folder from tomcat/webapps and you have *.war file there then just restart tomcat and it will deploy your webapp, but if you have no .war file there then tomcat can't retrieve it.